# Replacing an Empty List with None When Working With Option[List[Long]]

Tags: scala

I have some `Seq[Strings]` that I need to convert to `Option[Seq[Long]]`. I'm using the following:

```
val idsAsLongsUDF: Seq[String] => Option[Seq[Long]] = {
  idsSeqStr: Seq[String] =>
  import scala.util.Try
  Try(idsSeqStr.flatMap(id => Try(id.toLong).toOption)).toOption match {
    case Some(List()) => None: Option[Seq[Long]]
    case x => x
  } 
}
```

The catch is that an empty list returns as Some(List()) rather than None - which is correct but not desired. So the last few lines fix the empty list issue, by returning `None` when empty list is found.

I would like to get `Option[List[Long]]` returns suggested by this trial data:

```
val s = Seq("abc", null)   // None
val n : Seq[String] = null // None
val l = Seq("a", "1", "2") // Some(List(1,2))
```

Is there a more elegant or efficient means than what I have written?

Comment: There is no reason to have `null` in Scala code. Wrap it in `Option(valueForJava)` if it comes from outside and can be `null`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's probably more than one way to skin this cat, and elegant is in the eye of the beholder, but here's how I would write it:

```
val idsAsLongsUDF: Seq[String] => Option[Seq[Long]] = { idsSeqStr =>
  import scala.util.Try
  Option(idsSeqStr)
    .map(_.flatMap(id => Try(id.toLong).toOption))
    .filterNot(_.isEmpty)
}
```

Comment: Nice ... I'm leaning towards this with the replacement `.filterNot(_.isEmpty)` as `.filter(_.nonEmpty)`